# Generate a Pallette for an Image

Tags: code-golf, popularity-contest, image-processing

This is a successor to my previous Code Golf challenge, which may be found [here.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50314/approximate-a-given-image-using-only-colors-from-a-given-list)

This time, you are trying to determine what the contents of colors.txt should be.

Your task is to take from the input the path to an image and a number of colours, and write to colors.txt a list of that many colors chosen for that image.

Remember, you are generating pallettes to go with [this challenge.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50314/approximate-a-given-image-using-only-colors-from-a-given-list)

As usual, you are going for lowest score, but in this case, your score is given by `ceil(codeSize/(1+max(0,votes)))`, so upvotes will help you as well.

For **one or more** of the following images, you should test your generated pallettes (using one of the answers from [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/50314/approximate-a-given-image-using-only-colors-from-a-given-list) to test them) and post the results for a variety of pallette sizes:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Apart from lifting the restriction that on the number of contiguous cells in the result, this seems to be asking for the same as [Paint by Numbers](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/42217/8478).

Comment: So, do you think this should be deleted in that case?

Answer (score 1):

## Java

796 bytes

```
import java.awt.Color;import java.awt.image.*;import java.io.*;import java.util.*;import javax.imageio.*;public class P{public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception{Random R=new Random();Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);PrintStream o=new PrintStream("colors.txt");List<Color> col=new ArrayList<Color>();BufferedImage i=ImageIO.read(new File(in.nextLine()));int h=i.getHeight(),w=i.getWidth(),k=in.nextInt(),x,y,z=0,r,g,b;while(col.size()<k&&z<k*k){x=R.nextInt(w);y=R.nextInt(h);Color c=new Color(i.getRGB(x, y));r=5*(c.getRed()/5);g=5*(c.getGreen()/5);b=5*(c.getBlue()/5);c=new Color(r,g,b);if(!col.contains(c)){col.add(c);}z++;}while(col.size()<k)col.add(new Color(R.nextInt(256),+R.nextInt(256),R.nextInt(256)));for(Color c:col)o.println(c.getRed()+" "+c.getGreen()+" "+c.getBlue());}}
```

Picks random colors from the image, with each component rounded to the nearest multiple of 5, such that no color is selected twice. If, after n<sup>2</sup> selections, it has not yet found n distinct colors, it picks the rest entirely at random.

**Some sample results:**

The black spaceship in 10 colors:
[image]

In 25 colors:
[image]

In 50 colors:
[image]

In 200 colors:
[image]

The gold spaceship in 10 colors:

[image]

In 25 colors:

[image]

In 50 colors:

[image]

In 200 colors:

[image]

And, finally, the exploding globe in 10 colors:
[image]

In 25 colors:
[image]

In 50 colors:
[image]

And in 200 colors:
[image]